# User Input to string.xml

Tags: java, android, android-studio

right now I am creating an app which should get userinput via an EditText and then store this String into the strings.xml file. Can one of you tell me how to do this?

Comment: post some code and where are you stuck... This is too broad to answer and shows lack of investigation

Comment: This is not the way strings.xml works. You need to find an other way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You cant put a string inside the strings.xml as it is read only. you can put it in shared preferences though

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("input", "My String");
 editor.apply();
```

and to get it back

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("input", null);
```

Comment: Yeah this is the easiest solution. But depending on what OP wants to do, it could be better to use a database.